# Website cannot run on microsoft explorer 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I have created a webstie using Reactjs.
All things run as well, today I had meet to show my webstie.
The person that I met him, has a microsoft explorer 11.
The site is running perfect on chroome

We tried to run my website on it, we got a blank page, we got just the logo on tap window.
Please if there any one can help me to fix this problem and what is the code I have to add to my app.

my website is: https://944.dk

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I thing you did not understand my quastion, I have a problem just with internet explorer 11, all other browsers running good. @j08691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many features of modern javascript are not supported in Internet Explorer,

I can see in the IE console that it's crashing when trying to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
Which is not available in IE.

It's common practice to compile your web app with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), which can be used to manage compatibility issues with different browsers.

Comment: How to fix it do you think? @SpeedOfRound

Comment: By default, the generated project supports all modern browsers. Support for Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11 requires polyfills. For a set of polyfills to support older browsers, use react-app-polyfill from this link https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md Ref: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features#supported-browsers